# Iterative inOrder Binary Tree

Tags: python, iteration, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

I have the following class for the creation of a Binary Tree:

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None

    def root(self):
        return self._root

    def left(self):
        return self._left

    def right(self):
        return self._right

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._root is None

    def insert(self, element):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._root = element
            self._left = BinaryTree()
            self._right = BinaryTree()
        elif element <= self._root:
            self._left.insert(element)
        elif element > self._root:
            self._right.insert(element)

    def inOrder(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return []
        l = self._left.inOrder()
        l.append(self._root)
        l += self._right.inOrder()
        return l

    def preOrder(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return []
        l = [self._root]
        l += self._left.preOrder()
        l += self._right.preOrder()
        return l

    def inOrder_iterative(self):
        stack = []
        res = []
        aux = self

        while aux or stack:
           
            while aux:
                stack.append(aux)
                aux = aux._left

            aux = stack.pop()
            res.append(aux._root)
            aux = aux._right

        return res
```

When I insert the binary tree for inorder(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), I get it in order but with "None" preceding each number as follows:

`[None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None, 5, None, 6, None, 7, None, 8, None]`

I need it to output:

`[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

I can't seem to find what the error in the code is. Could you help me out please?

Thanks

EDIT:

Code to insert data into tree:

```
tree=BinaryTree()
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(8)
print('The binary tree is: ')
print('inOrder recursive', tree.inOrder())
print('inOrden iterative', tree.inOrder_iterative())
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'BinaryTree' object has no attribute '_raiz'`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77565493/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @Woodford Sure thing, just posted the example in the edit. Also, sorry about the 'raiz', it got in there by accident (whole code is translation from my code in spanish). Already corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
def iterative_inorder(root):
  stack = []
  current = root
  while current or stack:
    while current:
      stack.append(current)
      current = current.left
    if stack:
      current = stack.pop()
      print(current.data)
      current = current.right
```

Comment: What did you change? Why does it work where OP's code does not? Some explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def inOrder_iterative(self):
        stack = []
        res = []
        aux = self

        while aux or stack:
           
            while aux:
                stack.append(aux)
                aux = aux._left

            aux = stack.pop()
            res.append(aux._root)  # <-- aux may be empty here
            aux = aux._right

        return res
```

When you pop the next node off the stack you need to check to see if it's a leaf node before appending its value to the result. Change the indicated line to:

```py
if not aux.isEmpty():
    res.append(aux._root)
```

Comment: That is it!!! Thank you very much!!! Though I've got a question, why does evaluating with is.Empty() work, but when I try an if aux != None, it does not?

Comment: Also, I seem to see that instead of appending to the stack a single node I'm appending the whole tree "stack.append(aux)" ,but it seems to work? Am I missing something? I am not defining aux as the root of the tree until later

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not used the `isEmpty` method (which you *do* use in the recursive version). Change both occurrences of `aux` in your `while` conditions to `not aux.isEmpty()` and it will work.

As you have made a design decision to represent NIL as empty nodes (with `_root` equal to `None`), you should not check for `BinaryTree` instances to be `None`, but use the `isEmpty` logic.

```py
    def inOrder_iterative(self):
        stack = []
        res = []
        aux = self
    
        while not aux.isEmpty() or stack:
    
            while not aux.isEmpty():
                stack.append(aux)
                aux = aux._left
    
            aux = stack.pop()
            res.append(aux._root)
            aux = aux._right
    
        return res
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight! Why should I use the isEmpty logic and not check for instances to be None? I answered to another answer in the post that a if aux != None does not work but the isEmpty logic does

Comment: This is because you designed your tree in such a way that a NIL is a `BinaryTree` instance, and not `None`. I wouldn't do it that way, but as this is what your class does (for example in the constructor and `insert` method), you have to keep working with that pattern. The better practice is to design a tree with two classes: one for a node, and one for the tree (having a `root` member). But again, your design can work too, but then the idea is that the absence of a node is detected with `isEmpty` and not with `None`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try to design it as you say. Also, the tree is designed as it is because it is code given by our professor and we have to design the iterative methods using that code

Comment: I would have guessed it was given to you like that, so then you have to code using the same "agreements", and use `isEmpty` -- see the code in my answer.